# download from command line in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to get a file from Mysql webpage from command line Ubuntu:

```
wget "http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.3-1_all.deb"
```

But I'm getting error:

```
--2017-10-09 15:22:23--  http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.3-1_all.deb
Resolving dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)... 137.254.60.11
Connecting to dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)|137.254.60.11|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

What is the reason for this connection refuse error ?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: yes, but I have set the proxy based on IT department information !

Comment: In that case you probably should talk with them, when I tested it worked.